# Nlog with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Tags: mysql, nlog, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am working on NLog with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Based on the document, I know Pomelo based on [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector), but I don't know what's the value of dbProvider of the target in file nlog.config.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

NLog DatabaseTarget requires an ADO-provider. After checking MySqlConnector.dll using .Net Refactor, then it should be like this:

```
dbProvider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection,MySqlConnector"
```

Notice Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore is an EF Core provider (That underneath uses the ADO-provider)

Comment: See also the example in the docs: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-Target#mysql-and-net-core